# SQL: How to select first element based on a condition?

Tags: sql

I have a DB where i store several info about actions performed based on a date, so for example i have the following rows

```
"John", "Action1, "2017-02-20"
"John", "Action2, "2017-02-10"
"Mark", "Action3", "2016-09-21"
"Mark", "Action4", "2016-03-11"
```

If i would like to return the most recent activity for each user (John Action1, Mark Action3), can i do with a SQL sentence, or do i need to filter that in my source code once the SQL sentence has returned all the values?

Its a Postgres DB

Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The answer may be product specific.

Comment: also is that last field a true date, or just  a string.

Comment: What to return if there are two different actions for a user on that first date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical way of doing this uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col3 desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

`row_number()` is an ANSI standard function available in almost all databases.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
---sample data
WITH mytable([name], [action], [date]) AS
  (SELECT 'John',
          'Action1',
          '2017-02-20'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'John',
                    'Action2',
                    '2017-02-10'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Mark',
                    'Action3',
                    '2016-09-21'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Mark',
                    'Action4',
                    '2016-03-11') 
---actual query

SELECT t.[name],
       mt.[action]
FROM
  (SELECT [name],
          MAX([date]) AS [date]
   FROM [mytable]
   GROUP BY [name]) t
INNER JOIN [mytable] mt ON t.[name] = mt.[name]
AND t.[date] = mt.[date]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just run the following on a postgres instance - hopefully it's in good ANSI SQL and should work in other db's:

```
SELECT ac.name, ac.action, ac.time 
FROM action_times ac 
JOIN (SELECT name, MAX(time) AS time 
  FROM action_times GROUP BY name) mx
USING (name, time);
```

Which gives:

```
 name | action  |    time
------+---------+------------
 Mark | Action3 | 2016-09-21
 John | Action1 | 2017-02-20
(2 rows)
```

In old-style SQL (with optional extra table and column aliases):

```
SELECT ac.name, ac.action, ac.time 
FROM action_times ac, 
(SELECT tmp.name AS max_name, MAX(tmp.time) AS max_time 
  FROM action_times tmp GROUP BY tmp.name) mx 
WHERE ac.name = mx.max_name 
AND ac.time = mx.max_time;
```

The idea is to join your table to an aggregated version of itself and get extra info (`action` in this case). Those optional extra column and table aliases might make it easier to see what's going on.

Note that in this typical `GROUP BY` for a `SELECT` statement with an aggregation function (`MAX()` in this case) you should `GROUP BY` all non-aggregated columns (there is just one of them, `name`, in this case).

[setup stuff:-

```
create table action_times (name varchar(10), action varchar(10), time varchar(10));
insert into action_times values ('John', 'Action1', '2017-02-20');
insert into action_times values ('John', 'Action2', '2017-02-10');
insert into action_times values ('Mark', 'Action3', '2016-09-21');
insert into action_times values ('Mark', 'Action4', '2016-03-11');
```

Quick check:

```
select * from action_times order by name, time;
 name | action  |    time
------+---------+------------
 John | Action2 | 2017-02-10
 John | Action1 | 2017-02-20
 Mark | Action4 | 2016-03-11
 Mark | Action3 | 2016-09-21
(4 rows)
```

yup, looks ok]