# Why doesn't DISTINCT remove duplicates?

Tags: mysql

I'm currently trying to run the below query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT friend_id, hobbies as friend_hobby
                FROM all_friends
                WHERE friend_id NOT IN 
                     (SELECT distinct(friend_id)
                      FROM all_friends
                      WHERE (friend_type = 'Good' OR friend_type = 'Great')
                      );
```

**Expected Result**

```
friend_id | friend_hobby
--------------------
123       | Basketball
--------------------
345       | Painting
```

**Actual Result**

```
friend_id | friend_hobby
--------------------
123       | Basketball
--------------------
123       | Social Media
--------------------
123       | Reading
--------------------
123       | Hiking
--------------------
123       | Cooking
--------------------
345       | Painting 
--------------------
345       | Hiking 
--------------------
345       | Writing
--------------------
345       | Movies
--------------------
345       | Coding
```

Can anyone explain why the distinct clause doesn't return my **Expected Result?**

Is it because I'm also fetching friend_hobby, as well?

For note, I need to select both friend_id and hobbies, because I need to UNION with a Select statement fetching friend_id and hobbies. The hobbies in this select statement doesn't really matter, because they'll be replaced at some point.

What is the solution? I know adding group by at the end of the statement will remove the duplicate friend ids, but I'd prefer not to use group by without an aggregation occurring.

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't care about the hobby, and will drop it anyway later, you could add some literal in place of it: `SELECT DISTINCT friend_id, '-' as friend_hobby ...`

Comment: This pretty much is gonna be what I go with. Good suggestion, don't know why I didn't consider just having that literal in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DISTINCT itself doesn't remove duplicated entries; you need `group by` as well:

```
SELECT DISTINCT friend_id, friend_hobby from {whatever} group by friend_id
```

Comment: I was reading that it was kind of redundant to use both, though? What if wrapped friend_id in distinct like so ```SELECT DISTINCT(friend_id), friend_hobby from {whatever} group by friend_id```

Comment: @nick_rinaldi just forget `distinct` and focus on `group by`

Comment: With `group by` you can even get many types of aggregates. For example `SELECT friend_id, count(friend_hobby) as total_hobbies from {whatever} group by friend_id`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that DISTINCT is based on the "group" that you define

```
SELECT DISTINCT friend_id, hobbies as friend_hobby
```

In the line above, you're saying to give you all distinct pairs of `friend_id` and `hobbies` (friend_hobby).

However, your expected results seems to be more like: fetch me the first tuple that has a distinct id (if that sentence makes sense at all).

In this case, I believe doing something like the following post should help with what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42345019/5989233